# Not able to set background image through react component, getting error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my background image 'Sunny.jpg' in public folder.
I have written below code to set 'Sunny.jpg' as background image when end user enters location New York and press Enter but after pressing enter the background changes to the image 'Sunny.jpg' and immediately after that gives error
[image: error message]

Code written -

```
const WeatherStatus = (props) => {

    // Types of weather status "Clear","Clouds","Rain","Thunderstorm","Snow","Mist","Haze"

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container justify="center">
                <Paper elevation={10} 
                    style={{ height:"auto", width:"45%", marginTop:"10%", padding:"3%", opacity:"75%" }} >
                    {props.status !== "Status" ? (
                        <Typography 
                            style={{ fontSize:25 }}
                            align="center"
                            spacing="justify"
                        >{
                            (props.status === "Clear" && props.time < 19) ? 
                                (<WiDaySunny className=".wb-font-style" size={35}/>)
                                (document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('Sunny.jpg')")
                            : (props.status === "Clear" && props.time >= 19 && props.time < 4) ? 
                                (<WiMoonAltNew className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : (props.status === "Clouds") ? 
                                (<WiCloudy className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : (props.status === "Rain") ? 
                                (<WiRainWind className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : (props.status === "Thunderstorm") ? 
                                (<WiThunderstorm className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : (props.status === "Snow") ? 
                                (<WiSnowflakeCold className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : (props.status === "Mist" || props.status === "Haze") ? 
                                (<WiDayHaze className=".wb-font-style" size={35} />) 
                            : ('')
                        }{props.status}</Typography>
                    ) : (
                        <Typography 
                            style={{ fontSize:25 }}
                            align="center"
                            spacing="justify"
                        >Status</Typography>
                    )}
                </Paper>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a images folder in the `src` and put your images there...

```
└── src
    ├── App.css
    ├── App.js
    ├── App.test.js
    ├── images
    │   └── bg.jpg
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── logo.svg
    ├── reportWebVitals.js
    └── setupTests.js
```

use in `index.css` like so:

```
body {
    background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I want to change the background image when user clicks on button. Also there are many background images, as per the API output I want it to get change.

Answer (score 0):

you need the picture to be inside the src folder

```
import SunnyImg from 'src/img/Sunny.jpg'; // your image path
...
(document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(`${SunnyImg }`)")
...
```

you can also use dynamic import

```
const bgImg = reqire(`../img/${weather}.jpg`)
```

where the variable weather can be: 'Sunny', 'Rainy', etc.

Comment: I tried it but giving same error "TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement(...) is not a function"

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am making a weather application in which I am getting weather info from openWeatherMap API. That API contains weather type info (i.e. clear, rain, cloud, sunny) and based on weather type, I want to change the background image like if it is clear and daytime I want to show Sunny.jpg as background image, if it is raining, the background image should get changed to "rain.jpg".
So, to achieve this when API gets loaded through props I am validating it and if validation is true it will execute 
document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${SunnyImg})` and will change background img

Comment: @Siddhesh My comment was a review comment directed to this answer by kroken react.

Comment: @Siddhesh which folder is the picture in? you need the picture to be inside the src folder

Comment: yes there is a folder "src/Background Images/sunny.jpg" like this and import it tough correctly "import SunnyImg from '../../Background Images/sunny.jpg';"
Also in the code I wrote it as
(document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ SunnyImg })`)

but still getting error